# Syntax Error After deploy SpringBoot jar as service on ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, service

I have a springboot web application packaged as a jar file. And the product server is Ubuntu 14.04.1 with openjdk-8-jdk installed.

I can successfully run the application using:

```sh
sudo java -jar /home/myUser/my_web_app.jar
```

Then I make this appliaction as a SystemV service by following commands:

```sh
sudo useradd webUser
sudo passwd webUser
sudo chown webUser:webUser /home/myUser/my_web_app.jar
sudo chmod 500 /home/myUser/my_web_app.jar
sudo ln -s /home/myUser/my_web_app.jar /etc/init.d/my_web_app
```

After that, when I run:

```sh
sudo service my_web_app start
```

And error raise as:

```sh
/etc/init.d/my_web_app: 1: /etc/init.d/my_web_app: Syntax error: ")" unexpected.
```

I wonder what cause this error and how to reslove it. Thanks.

BTW, Same method works on my devlopment machine (Ubuntu 14.04.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
sudo chmod 500 /home/myUser/my_web_app.jar
sudo ln -s /home/myUser/my_web_app.jar /etc/init.d/my_web_app
```

**Problem #1:** regular executable JAR files are not an executable format that the OS recognizes<sup>1</sup>.

Setting the execute bit on a regular JAR file won't help.  The OS kernel does not know how to run it.  To run a regular JAR, you have to execute the command `java -jar /path/to/the.jar`.  If necessary, you can create a simple wrapper script to do this.

<sup>1 - There is a way to generate a special "fully executable" SpringBoot JAR file which has an shell script prepended to it; see ["Installing Spring Boot Applications"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html).  This is one way to get around this problem, though the documentation states that these special JAR files cause problems for some tools.</sup>

**Problem #2:** The files in `/etc/init.d` are supposed to be service scripts.

They are not simply the executable for a service.  The scripts are supposed to be shell scripts that understand verbs such as `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `reload` and so on.  And (AFAIK) they must be coded as `sh` compatible shell scripts.  Here is an article that describes the structure of service scripts:

- https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-linux-daemons-init-scripts

(But read Problem #4 first!!)

**Problem #3**: Running a service as `root` can be a security risk.

It is better to create a (non-privileged) service account to run the service.   This is especially important if the service is exposed to the network.  (If the bad guys can "hack" the service over the network and cause it to do undesirable things, the fact that it is running as root places the entire system at risk.)

**Problem #4:** `/etc/init.d/` scripts are obsolete.

If you are using a recent Ubuntu release (15.04 or later), those `/etc/init.d/` scripts are the "legacy" way of configuring.  The current iteration of the `initd` mechanism is `systemd`.  It uses `systemd`  unit files  files rather than service scripts.  The following article gives more information:

- https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-linux-daemons-init-scripts

The `systemd` service includes for legacy service scripts, but they are not as powerful, flexible and ... concise ... as unit files.

**Problem #5:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS has reached end-of-life.

You should upgrade to 16.04 LTS or preferably 18.04 LTS.  It is unwise to use an end-of-life operating system for your production server(s).

---

Note that there is a lot of documentation, and many articles on the web about both the old and new ways of configuring services.  ( Google is your friend. )

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and good advices. Getting familiar with linux service mechanism is very helpful to resolve problems like this. And after some seaching I found that springboot offers a default service configuration practice. And I will add that as another answer ( You can add that to your answer if you like ). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to @Stephne C's detailed answer. After some seach I found spring boot offer an out-of-box service practice [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) for Ubuntu and CentOS.

The main mistake I made is not package my project as executable jar.

To make springboot jar executable, edit POM file, add `<executbale>` tag into `<configuration>` tag of spring-boot-maven-plugin as blow:

```
<project>
   ...
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         ...
      </plugins>
   </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Package and upload the new executable jar to the server

`chown` the jar to a nologin user, the service will run by it's owner.

`chmod 500` the jar to give it executable permission.

add a soft link to /etc/init.d to regsiter it as a service.

run the service, so far so good.

But as @Stephen C said, the default option is neither secure enough nor very up-to-date. I think is better to just package a fat jar and configure the service by hand in production enviornment.