# Systemd service enabled but does not start

Tags: linux, service, systemd

I have a custom Spring Boot web application running on a Linux virtual machine. I have a `systemd` script to start/restart the application.

I have tried changing to `WantedBy=default.target` and it still does not work. I have tried adding `After` or `Type` and still does not work

```
[Unit]

Description=SpringBootSampleApp

[Service]

WorkingDirectory=/home/mecpro

ExecStop=/usr/bin/sudo /home/mecpro/webapp/webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /home/mecpro/webapp/webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war


[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My console screen looks like this

> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-08-12 13:26:27 UTC; 22ms ago
>        Main PID: 9104 (sudo)
>           Tasks: 2 (limit: 4675)

When I run `systemctl status webapp.service`, I get this

> webapp.service - SpringBootSampleApp
>    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-08-12 13:26:27 UTC; 3min 17s ago
>    Process: 9104 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /home/mecpro/webapp/webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (code=exited, status=2)
>    Main PID: 9104 (code=exited, status=2)
>   Aug 12 13:26:28 x01133361 sudo[9104]: /home/mecpro/webapp/webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war: 2: /home/mecpro/webapp/webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>   Aug 12 13:26:27 x01133361 systemd[1]: Started SpringBootSampleApp.
>   Aug 12 13:26:27 x01133361 systemd[1]: webapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
>   Aug 12 13:26:27 x01133361 systemd[1]: webapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Aug 12 13:26:27 x01133361 sudo[9104]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/mecpro ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/home/mecpro/webapp/webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
>   Aug 12 13:26:27 x01133361 sudo[9104]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
>   Aug 12 13:26:27 x01133361 sudo[9104]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

This is my first question on StackOverflow so kindly excuse if the question is badly formatted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`, `webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` must be a script or a binary executable by your system

Comment: But I have an exact similar script running for another application which is also deployed using a war file and it seems to run perfectly. So, this mean there is a problem with this source code?

Comment: I don't know what the `.war` file format is, but this kind of syntax error is common when the file can't be executed (and is not about privilegies), see this answer [syntax-error-after-deploy-springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56955793/2498790)

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex. That answer link was not exactly what I was looking for, but it gave me the solution. I had to add a section to my pom.xml file in my source code to make the war or jar file fully executable. Thank you once again.

Comment: write up a complete answer and post it below. You can accept your own answer after 48? hrs and gain valuable reputation points ;-). Good luck.

Comment: @AamirKhan you're welcome, I'm glad you solved. shellter is right, you should post an answer with the solution, maybe change the title and tags, more towards spring-boot and `.war` files and less about systemd, so it can help others.